# i have an error code like this: Podfile Syntax error, unexpected end of input what can i do to fix this?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

ive been trying to add cocoapods to my xcode project but im getting this error code. ill attach a picture of the pod file code so you can see what ive typed in. hopefully someone can help me with this as i cant understand why its not working...

Podfile:

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Aquavoid' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

## pods for Aquavoid

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

target 'AquavoidTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# pods for testing

target 'AquavoidUITests' do
# pods for testing

end

error code:  [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end

Comment: Try removing your first 3 `End`s

Comment: Podfiles are case sensitive. It's `end`, not `End`, it's `pod` not `Pod`.

Comment: And next time paste your code in the body of your question. Text in images is not indexable, searchable and can't be copied.

Comment: Hi, ive tried everything thats been said and still no luck. sorry about the text in images i wasn't sure what i was meant to do. i saw someone said to try pod install --verbose but when i didi it nothing was installing...